# how to loop through array in awk

Tags: awk

Once I split the variable and assign it to proxyset. How do I travers proxyset array with for in. In the below example print var only return 1 2

```
PROXY_PASS_MAPPING=abc|123,xyz|456

awk -v rep=$PROXY_PASS_MAPPING '

BEGIN      { split(rep,proxyset,",")
             print proxyset[1]
             for(var in proxyset ){
              print var
              split(var,a,"|")                                   
              site[a[1]]=a[2]
             }
             print site["abc"]                   
           } '
```

Answer (score 0):

After line `for(var in proxyset ){`, `var` contains only the index value, not the value in `proxyset` array.

So, use `proxyset[var]` to obtain the value.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

PROXY_PASS_MAPPING="abc|123,xyz|456"

awk -v rep="${PROXY_PASS_MAPPING}" '
BEGIN {
    split(rep, proxyset, ",")
    for(var in proxyset) {
        print "proxyset[" var "]=<" proxyset[var] ">"
        split(proxyset[var], a, "|")
        site[a[1]]=a[2]
    }
    print site["abc"]
}'
```

Output:

```
proxyset[1]=<abc|123>
proxyset[2]=<xyz|456>
123
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`, the `split()` command returns the number of elements that were separated. In your case if you want to split on `','`, you would simply do

```bash
n=split(PROXY_PASS_MAPPING,pp,",")
```

Which would split the contents of your `PROXY_PASS_MAPPING` variable into the array `pp` returning the number of elements in `n`. You simply use your normal loop `for (i=1; i<=n; i++)` to loop over the elements in `pp`.

A full example could be:

```bash
awk -v "PROXY_PASS_MAPPING=abc|123,xyz|456" '
  BEGIN {
    n=split(PROXY_PASS_MAPPING,pp,",")
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
      print pp[i]
}'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -v "PROXY_PASS_MAPPING=abc|123,xyz|456" '
>   BEGIN {
>     n=split(PROXY_PASS_MAPPING,pp,",")
>     for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
>       print pp[i]
> }'
abc|123
xyz|456
```

If you wanted to split on both `'|'` and `','` to obtain all four values in the array, you could simply replace `","` with `/[|,]/`.

**Example**

```
$ awk -v "PROXY_PASS_MAPPING=abc|123,xyz|456" '
>   BEGIN {
>     n=split(PROXY_PASS_MAPPING,pp,/[|,]/)
>     for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
>       print pp[i]
> }'
abc
123
xyz
456
```

Up to you. Let me know if you have questions.